# how to print 'add term' taxonomy form into block

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

I have a taxonomy vocabulary named "jenis dokumen". I want to let anonymous users add terms within this vocabulary. I'm trying to add a block and render that form to add new term using PHP filter, but it's failing.

This is my code:

```
include_once(drupal_get_path('module','taxonomy') . '/taxonomy.admin.inc' );
return drupal_render(drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', jenis_dokumen));
```

Can anyone help?

now i have success with this.

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load(2, FALSE);
module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
return drupal_render(drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', $vocabulary));
```

but, there is a default value in field name 'Jenis Dokumen'
how can i get blank (no value) in field?

Answer (score 5):

A couple things:

- The function [taxonomy_form_term()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.admin.inc/function/taxonomy_form_term/7) expects the $vocabulary parameter to be an object with a "machine_name" property
- You should wrap the vocab name in quotes
- More elegant to use [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) instead of include_once()

So:

```
if ($vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('jenis_dokumen')) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
  $edit = array();
  $taxonomy_form = drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', $edit ,$vocabulary);
  return drupal_render($taxonomy_form);
}
```

Comment: +1 you could go one step further and use [`taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load/7) to load up the full vocab before passing it through

Comment: i implement your code, now i have an error message like this.

    Notice: Undefined index: taxonomy_form_term in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 765 of E:\www\for-roni\includes\form.inc).
    Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'taxonomy_form_term' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 800 of E:\www\for-roni\includes\form.inc).

Comment: @Clive nice call, I've updated my answer! :)

Comment: @DE51GN please try again with the updated answer, just copy and paste it to avoid typos plz.

Comment: thank for helping me Alex.

i'm still get error message with your code.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: taxonomy_form_term in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 765 of E:\www\for-roni\includes\form.inc).`,
`Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'taxonomy_form_term' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 800 of E:\www\for-roni\includes\form.inc).`
`Notice: Undefined index: #term in path_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter() (line 233 of E:\www\for-roni\modules\path\path.module).`
`Notice: Undefined index: #term in path_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter() (line 235 of E:\www\for-roni\modules\path\path.module).`

Comment: @DE51GN apologies, I had another typo in my answer. Plz copy & paste again i've tested it locally and it works!